# changing animation in response to input

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I currently have an animation which runs as soon as I launch the app. Now I want to select another animation which plays in response to user input. e.g If I press left, the animation for walking left replaces the current sprite's animation. I've tried adding a new `textureAtlas` in the `keyDown` function but that doesn't work.

In other words I want the app to display the idle animation of the sprite when no Input is present. Then If I hit a button (left for example) It should change to walking animation.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private Animation animation;
    private float elapsedTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet.atlas"));
        animation = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        //sprite.draw(batch);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
            textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet2.atlas"));
        }
            return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that TextureAtlases must be disposed before you lose your reference to them, or a memory leak occurs. When you call `textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas...` you are losing your reference to the first TextureAtlas that you instantiated.

Comment: So How would I prevent this? Should I use a third textureAtlas which will hold the first TextureAtlas so I may dispose it? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Call dispose on it before changing the reference to something else. Typically you would only be doing this when switching stages. If your game isn't huge, you should probably only have one Atlas, though. Read up on AssetManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many different animations you have (maybe it is just idle, walk_right, walk_left, maybe a couple of others...), you could just load all the textureAtlases and create various animations - like you did in your create() method

```
//simple example ...
animationIdle = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas1.getRegions());
animationLeft = new Animation(1/7f, textureAtlas2.getRegions());
//etc
```

Then have code somewhere (not in the render method), determine what the "current animation" should be. Using your code as an example:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
  if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
     // Maybe check to make sure the currentAnimation is not already the 
     // left animation, if it isn't, swap it:
       currentAnimation = animationLeft;
       //set elapsedTime to 0 to "Restart the new animation" at its beginning
       elapsedTime = 0;
  }
```

Then your render() method just draws the current animation, and the elapsedTime was reset as needed(if you changed the animation you wanted):

```
batch.draw(currentAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
//increment elapsedTime after drawing animation at least once??
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

The above code is rough, not necessarily syntax free or structured the best, but gives you an idea of what might work.